# Is there a way for V8 to suspend code execution and back to caller thread?

Tags: javascript, v8

I want to implement V8 engine to interpret script which contain function that blocking script execution until it gets user response.
Is there a way to suspend execution and resume it later in Google V8 Engine?

Comment: not for browser, but for embedding javascript into program.

Comment: What kind of user response would start the script again?

Comment: client response via network packet